# Can I merge all my JS and CSS in one file using WP?

Tags: plugins, css

I have a website loaded with plugins, I need them. 
Is it possible to reduce the amount of js and CSS generated by those plugins?
the site is finsof.net

Comment: Reducing the amount of CSS and JS and combining CSS and JS is too separate things. What did you actually want to do? Combining CSS and JS is no longer considered a way to improve performance, if that's what you meant. Not with HTTP2.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of Plugins on the market which fullfill your task.
Most common is https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge and minify **only** you could use this plugin:

`merge minify refresh` plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/merge-minify-refresh

But, You might wish to try to cache your website to make it load faster.

I recommend using `W3 Total Cache` Plugin for Merge + Minify + optimize Above the fold content + use Critical CSS and Caching + tons of features.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Having you said your website is full of plugins I assume it runs slow;
try to mesaure its speed using [GTMetirx.com](https://gtmetrix.com/) and [Google Page insight](https://pagespeed.web.dev/) and read there recommendations and try to fix one by one....You will end with a very fast website if you can meet those requirments.

Here are some startup guides:

[How to Speed Up Your WordPress Website (Simple Guide)- 14 Min YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrY6a-lsLp8)

[How to Speed Up Your WordPress Site (Ultimate 2022 Guide)](https://kinsta.com/learn/speed-up-wordpress/)

> Please don't forget to backup your website's files and database before
> making any changes.
>
> It is strongly recommended to backup from your cPanel and be in
> safe side and download a local copy of your backup for everything.
>
> This is very critical

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is. You can use a plugin for it. May be try with this:
https://bg.wordpress.org/plugins/fast-velocity-minify/